# Transform the problem of finding the smallest enclosing circle on the surface of sphere to smallest circle in carthesian space

Tags: optimization, spherical-coordinates, spheres, stereographic-projections

I have points on the surface of a sphere and I need to find the cutting-plane that cuts off all points and also cuts off the minimum possible volume to do so.

There is the https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/subdir/software/miniball.html miniball lib which is very fast in finding minimum enclosing circle of points in carthesian spaces.

Is it possible to transform the given problem to carthesian space so that I can solve it using such a library?

Comment: Maybe use stereographic projection?

Comment: Just checked on wikipedia “Circles on the sphere that do not pass through the point of projection are projected to circles on the plane.” So this seems to be an excellent idea! Just wonder whether the smallest circle on the plane also will be the smallest on the sphere